# Using a global object in React Context that is not related to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have a global object that is available to my app where I can retrieve the value anywhere and also set a new value anywhere. Currently I have only used Context for values that are related to state i.e something needs to render again when the value changes. For example:

```
import React from 'react';
const TokenContext = React.createContext({
    token: null,
    setToken: () => {}
});

export default TokenContext;

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Title from './Title';
import TokenContext from './TokenContext';

function App() {

  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);


  return(
    <TokenContext.Provider value={{ token, setToken }}>
      <Title />
    </TokenContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How would I approach this if I just want to store a JS object in context (not a state) and also change the value anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The global context concept in React world was born to resolve problem with passing down props via multiple component layer. And when working with React, we want to re-render whenever "data source" changes. One way data binding in React makes this flow easier to code, debug and maintain as well.
So what is your specific purpose of store a global object and for nothing happen when that object got changes? If nothing re-render whenever it changes, so what is the main use of it?

Prevent re-render in React has multiple ways like `useEffect` or old `shouldComponentUpdate` method. I think they can help if your main idea is just prevent re-render in some very specific cases.

Comment: The global object caches data input from various components. When an upload button is pressed (within one of the components) I access this global object to get the data. So the data doesn't cause any re-renders.

Comment: If so, I highly recommend use `window` instead. Because, that is the problem `React` does not resolve and have no reason to resolve.

Comment: I think window is generally considered to be a hack and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as state management libraries like Redux.

You have a global object (store) and you query the value through context, but you also need to add [`forceUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) because mutating the object won't trigger a render as its not part of React API:

```
const globalObject = { counter: 0 };

const Context = React.createContext(globalObject);

const Consumer = () => {
  const [, render] = useReducer(p => !p, false);
  const store = useContext(Context);

  const onClick = () => {
    store.counter = store.counter + 1;
    render();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Render</button>
      <div>{globalObject.counter}</div>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={globalObject}>
      <Consumer />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit charming-lake-iyk04]

Comment: Would I need `const [, render] = useReducer(p => !p, false);` ? I don't need to re-render when the value changes. I just need the value stored so I can access it in another page. For example I tap "upload" in one of the pages and then access the global object.

Comment: And how the other component will know that the value is updated? You must render the other component.

Comment: The upload button will just call an api with the value in the global object. This needs to render again?

Comment: I don't know what your specific case. You should deduce it from the answer, again, on changing global object, other components won't get notified, you must render them inorder to see the change.